# AWS Data Pipeline - Components, Instances and Attempts and Pipeline Status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

Documentation on AWS Data Pipeline describes the Data Pipeline related concepts of Components, Instances and Attempts here.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-tasks-scheduled.html

I am trying to identify the status of a data pipeline ( whether its running or finished) using DescribeObjects API method described here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeObjects.html

Using this API method I can get the status of a particular object using @status field.

To identify whether a data pipeline is in running state or in some other state, does it suffice to check objects in "INSTANCE" state? or do I need to check objects in "COMPONENT" state and "ATTEMPT" state as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the overall state of the pipeline, you could use DescribePipeline as opposed to DescribeObjects. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/APIReference/API_DescribePipelines.html

There is an attribute called `pipelineState` which will tell you the state/status of the pipeline. I"ve seen the following pipeline states

`"RUNNING", "VALIDATING", "WAITING_FOR_RUNNER", "WAITING_FOR_DEPENDENCIES", "ACTIVATING", "SCHEDULED", "PENDING", "FINISHED", "INACTIVE"`